# Android: Textview can't align vertically

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am not able to vertically align my text in list view item.
This is my code for the item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="@color/line_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_background_circle"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_terrain"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The text goes always to the top of the list item.

This is the list view of the item:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_buttons"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</ListView>
```

In Android studio preview the text **is aligned vertically**! Is the possible that some parent (list view) is doing the mess?

Comment: Your ImageView is aligned to the top left of the parent. Your textview is aligned to the top of the Imageview...

Comment: After a test of your code, the text is centered vertically.
Your picture is not too small? Or you may be using another item like a "land"? Or maybe your text contains space and line return?
You do not change the height of text programmatically? A listview normally not change the disposition of its elements, it's weird, it intrigues me.

Comment: Nop :/ I re-edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited layout code. Please check this code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
   android:background="@color/line_color"
   android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_background_circle"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_terrain"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/func_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"  
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:text="Testing String" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_below` instead of `android:layout_alignTop`